# C code wont execute

Tags: c, encryption

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 void encrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{ int i;
 for ( i=0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
    }
    else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
    {
        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
    }
}
}

 void decrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{ inti;
 for ( i=0; i < num; i++)
{
    if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
    }
    else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
    {
        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
    }
    }
}

int main ()
{
char text[10];
static const char encrypt[] = "2";
static const char decrypt[] = "1";
int shift;
char cipher[25];
int result1;
int result2;
int num;
int i;



printf( "Enter operation: encrypt or decrypt/n" );
printf( "Press 1 to Encrypt or 2 to Decrypt" );
scanf("%c",&text) ;
printf( "Enter shift key" );
scanf("%d",&shift) ;
printf("Enter text to encrypt/decrypt") ;
fflush(stdin);
scanf( "%c",&cipher) ;

num = strlen (cipher);

result1 = strcmp (text, encrypt);
result2 = strcmp (text, decrypt);

if(result1 == 0)
{
    decrypting(cipher, shift, num);
}
else{exit(0);}

if(result2 == 0)
{
    encrypting(cipher, shift, num);
}
else{exit(0);}

printf("Result");
printf("%d",cipher);
}
```

This my code for a simple program that encypts or decrypts a string based on user choice.

The code produce this error when i try to compile, could anyone explain whats the problem.

> C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Ceaser Cipher Dr X\First try.c||In function 'main':|
>
> C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Ceaser Cipher Dr X\First try.c|65|error: too few arguments to function 'decrypting'|
>
> C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Ceaser Cipher Dr X\First try.c|21|note: declared here|
>
> C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Ceaser Cipher Dr X\First try.c|71|error: too few arguments to function 'encrypting'|
>
> C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Ceaser Cipher Dr X\First try.c|6|note: declared here|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Edit: I've corrected my codes but now after the user inputs the string for cipher, the program will automatically terminates.

Comment: Read the error again. It says arguments are missing in the function calls of encrypting, and decrypting

Comment: There is too few arguments to function 'decrypting'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `int i` in the function header, and declare as local variable:

```
void encrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{
        int i;
        for ( i=0; i < num; i++)
        {
                if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
                }
                else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
                {
                        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
                }
        }
}

void decrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{
        int i;
        for ( i=0; i < num; i++)
        {
                if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
                }
                else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
                {
                        cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your encrypting and decrypting functions take 4 parameters while you pass in only 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your both functions (Encrypting and Decrypting) get four arguments but you pass three arguments to them in your code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument in the function. The error description is self explanatory.

Uaing 3 args instead of the required 4

Answer (score 0):

As decrypting function has 4 parameter ,so you have to pass four argument ,you are just passing 3 arguments only in decrypting function .